# Spring-Spock loads context once for multiple tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, groovy, spock

I have question about context loading during spock tests. My classes look like this (I have more than one class using the same context):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:context/mycontext.xml")
class SampleSpec extends Specification { 
//implementation ommited
}
```

The problem is when I run tests separately (mvn clean test -Dtest=SampleSpec) everything runs as expected. But when I run all test at once (mvn clean test) they will fail (they rely on fresh context loading). The point is that I need load the context for every test class separately. I wonder if there is a way how to do this.

In the log file I see (only once):

```
Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [context/mycontext.xml]
//..other contexts are loaded
```

EDIT: I am using Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE, gmavenplus-plugin (version 1.5) and **spockframework**.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`@DirtiesContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) eg:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:context/mycontext.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class SampleSpec extends Specification {
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried it, but now getting compilation error:
`error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DirtiesContext$ClassMode
  location: package org.springframework.test.annotation`

`error: an enum annotation value must be an enum constant`

Did I miss something?

Annotation looks like this:
`@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`

Comment: The error was caused by gmaven-plugin. I switched to gmavenplus-plugin and code compiles now, but it still loads context only once.

Comment: Use `AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD` not `AFTER_CLASS`

Comment: Thanks for response. Still the same issue even with `AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD`. Excerpt from the log file:

`Running test.SampleSpec
2015-09-17 13:24:31,167 [           main] INFO  ry.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [context/mycontext.xml]
//other contexts are loaded, tests are run
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 36.051 sec` And the next line is `Running test.AnotherTest`. I would expect context loading line here. Am I missing something?